# Visa for Tanzania, Africa and visa runs

Tags: africa, tanzania

I want to get a visa for Tanzania, Africa. I am planning on working there and hopefully stay there. But I think the only visa I can get is a visitor visa. So if I leave every 3 months, how long do I have to wait before returning?

3 May 2018 update:
I have been here a few months now, and want to clarify that I work in the medical field via the internet with the US. I don't work here in Tanzania, I do plan on starting a business at some point and will do it the legal way, get registered and get the correct type of visa. I apologize for my ignorance and now know the process.

Comment: You plan to work in Tanzania on a visitor visa? That seems rather problematic in and of itself.

Comment: Always curious when people openly admit to intending to break the law with a username attached to their name and photo. So many bad ideas, all at once!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In Tanzania there are two ways to get a work visa from immigration.  One is to apply before arriving.  In general, immigration will not approve applications for work visa if you are already in the country on a tourist visa.  The second way (which a friend of mine tried recently and surprisingly it worked) is to apply at the airport upon arrival.  This means waiting to get your visa until you actually arrive in Tanzania.  On the visa application at the airport there is a box to check which type of visa you are requesting.  Tell the immigration official that you want to start up a business in Tanzania.  I believe the cost of this visa is $250 and is good for either 6 months or a year.

Comment: The asker doesn't say they want to start a business. Are you assuming things that aren't inthe question, or are you advising them to lie to the immigration officer? The latter is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

That's a famously bad idea.

[image: EMPLOYMENT WITH OR WITHOUT PAY PROHIBITED]

- It's illegal. Working without a work visa
- It puts you in a very precarious situation. All that's required to jeopardize your stay is a suspicious immigration officer. Since you probably can get a visa on arrival, you're at the mercy of the immigration services every time you cross the border. And if you need to apply for a visa from a Consulate, it's even worse.
- There's no better way to be red-flagged as an illegal "casual" worker than stay the full duration of your visa every time, and repeat that continuously.
- If you are planning to do border runs, coming to Tanzania from five of its neighbouring countries requires [a yellow fever vaccination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Tanzania#Mandatory_vaccination). Ouch.
- The population's attitude towards LGBT could put you in danger if you're heterosexual (not making any judgment or assumption here).

Comment: The yellow fever vaccination is good for at least ten years, if not for life, so it's not particularly troublesome over time.  The paragraph about attitudes towards LGBT is perplexing.  Did you mean to write "homosexual"?

Comment: Yf-Vax: true, but it is a painful one, with after-effects for a few days that are unpleasant.

Comment: I got mine about 18 months ago, with mild soreness for a few days.  In other words, it was as you describe, but the unpleasantness was very slight, certainly less unpleasant than the stiffness one experiences after exercising when out of shape.

Comment: How is sexuality relevant?